# I want to texture paint but it says "Missing texture, detected!"

Tags: texture-painting

[image]

After clicking to try and paint, I see the missing texture error warning.

Answer (score 11):

Blender Guru's video helps explain it. https://youtu.be/nht2RoYBUfA?t=212

I know 10 images may seem excessive, but I know a lot of new people may get lost and would need it.

1. First, create a new image or open an old one. (I will create a new one)
   [image: First, create a new image or open an old one. (I will create a new one)]
2. Create the image. (mine's name will be "Untitled")
   [image: Create the image. (it's name will be "Untitled")]
3. You would get a black image.
   [image: You would get a black image.]
4. But you still can't paint. That's because the image isn't connected to the texture of the model.
   [image: But you still can't paint. That's because the image isn't connected to the texture of the model.]
5. Go to "Shading" from the top bar.
   [image: Go to "Shading" from the top bar.]
6. Add a new image texture. (Add>Texture>Image Texture)
   [image: Add a new image texture. (Add>Texture>Image Texture)]
7. Connect the nodes. (Color-Base Color)
   [image: Connect the nodes. (Color-Base Color)]
8. Press the Image button and choose the image you created or opened before. ("Untitled" in my case)
   [image: Press the Image button and choose the image you created or opened before. ("Untitled" in my case)]
9. Selected.
   [image: Selected.]
10. Now you can paint!
    [image: Now you can paint!]

Answer (score 0):

some things to try:

1.) add a texture in the "texture slots

[image]

2.) UV Unwrap object
[image]

3.)Add an "Image Texture" to the base color and then select your texture painted material by clicking the little dropdown instead of picking an image file

4.) this dude has a recent run down worth watching:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AnRQhH3fEDY
[image]